# Set condition when numbers are chosen in radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to show the condition only when values ​​are chosen for the three `radioButtons`, no matter the options. As it is, I choose an option just and this condition already appears, but that's not what I want. And I left it as `'2'` em `"input.radio1 == '2'`, but just as an example, the idea is that it is valid for any chosen value.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          radioButtons("radio1", label = h3("Choose 1"),
                                       choices = list("Option1" = 2, "Option2" = 3, "Option3" = 4), 
                                       selected = ""),
                          
                          radioButtons("radio2", label = h3("Choose 2"),
                                       choices = list("Option4" = 2, "3 clusters" = 3, "Option5" = 4), 
                                       selected = ""),
                          
                          radioButtons("radio3", label = h3("Choose 3"),
                                       choices = list("Option6" = 2, "Option1" = 3, "Option8" = 4), 
                                       selected = ""),
                          
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "input.radio1 == '2'|| input.radio2 == '2'|| input.radio3 == '2'",
                            
                            tags$hr(style="border-color: black;"),
                            tags$p(h3("Are you satisfied with this solution?")),
                            radioButtons( "satisfaction","", choices = list("Yes" = 1,"Not " = 2),selected = 1))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                          )))
                      
             )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update**

From what I've seen you have to use `&&` instead of `||` in `condition`. Now I just need to adjust the issue that it can be any choice of `radiobutton1`, `radiobutton2` and `radiobutton3`, not just option `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this `condition = "input.radio1 && input.radio2 && input.radio3"`, the conditionalPanel should appear only if the user has selected a choice for all 3 radio buttons.